# Retrieve Agent seizing fleet transporter as a parameter

Tags: anylogic

I'm using a popluation of "flow" in main that are injected through nodes and paths placed on top of a map in main, i have differents fleets with proper agent type for each fleet, flows use seize/moveto transporter blocks to move these fleets (which are used as a parameter)  in the nodes with a process and some functions defined, and i have created a function on main to export the name of the node being entered for each fleet which is exectuted in the "On enter node" block of the Transporterfleet in question;

I would like to get the "flow" agent id of the population " flows" present in main, thank you in advance for your support!

```
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dmg.png][1] 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dmg.png[2]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dmg.png][3]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dmg.png][4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the keywords you can use in "on enter node". One of them is `unit`, which refers to the actual transporter.

So simply use `unit.id` and it will use it. Of course, you must set the "Transporter type" setting in your TransporterFleet object to the agent type of your transporters that actually have a field "id", otherwise you will get an error.

Please read more about these keywords here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling

Comment: Hello @Benjamin, Thank you so much for your feedback! Transporter type is already set up in the fleet as the agent type, there is another agent "flow" which uses the very different transporter fleets in its process , this "flow" agent is then injected through nodes and paths in main. Fleets are defined in main as are the functions ii'm using

Comment: I have added some images to illustrate the config i'm using (side note :" Flux" is" Flow")

Comment: Hi, that screenshot is really not helpful... Also, do you still have a problem after working with my suggestion? If so, please be more specific of what you tried and what the (remaining?) problem is...

Comment: Hi Benjamin, i'm trying to get the flow "flux" associated to the transporter entering the node.

Comment: the unit keyword gave me as a result "population [80]" , and this is not really actually what i'm trying to have because if well i understand it'll get the agent defined in the fleet, the agent happen to be the transporter type. I want to know with which flow the transporter is entering the node.

Comment: Thank you in advance

Comment: Remark : fleets are used as a parameter in Seize blocks in the agent "Flux" of the population "Flux" /// I have made some changes to my post to be more specific

Comment: Mate, can you simply rephrase the whole question, it is getting more and more confusing :) Do add clear screenshots, show what you already tried, show what you want to get. Also, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help but you need to spoon-feed us very cleary with your problem :-) cheers